# loop to find the date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am new to php and mysql programing and I have a question in working with the date.

There is a date field that stores the date in the table

eg `2013-05-27, 2013-05-24, 2013-05-22`

I need to retrieve the latest 3 days data for further processing, first is locate today's date, if cannot find, then will locate yesterday's data, if cannot find, then locate the date before yesterday's data etc. Then I have the below code:

```
$date1=date('Y-m-d');
$date1_1="";
$datefound="";
while( $datefound <> ""){
    $date1_1_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jom_c1 where date ='" .$date1. "'");
    if($date1_1_1){
    $datefound = $date1;
}else{
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' - 1 day'));
}
}
echo $datefound; 
?>
```

however, it seems like the loop is not running, much appreciated if someone can give me a hints with it.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider using SQL properly,
ie

```
select * from jom_c1 where date <= curdate() order by date desc limit 3
```

rather than looping.

(Your loop doesn't run much, because as soon as date is found, it stops)

Comment: @Mifeet Possibly not. I've added an explicit sort

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the while block is not executing is that you set `$datefound=""` but your condition is `while ($datefound<>"")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the most current date that has a record in `jom_c1`, then try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM jom_c1 WHERE date <= CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you're looking for the latest three dates, then use `LIMIT 3` instead of `LIMIT 1`.

The PHP code would look like this:

```
$datefound = "";
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM jom_c1 WHERE date <= CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1');
if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $datefound = $row['date'];
}
echo $datefound;
```

Note that `mysql_query` is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), however.

---

**Edit:** 
If there are multiple records for one day, then use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM jom_c1 WHERE date <= CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Distinct will leave out duplicate records.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i have tried. But one thing, we have 16 records in one day, can i group to just store 1 record in the array with the same "date" ?

Comment: thank you very much again, i have tried it but with LIMIT 3, then it only show 2 records Array ( [date] => 2013-05-22 ) Array ( [date] => 2013-05-21 ) it should have a 2013-05-23. have i done something wrong ?